# AngularJS img ng-src binding doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to bind the ng-src of a img with a $scope variable but it doesn't refresh the image when the variable changes.

**THE HTML**

```
<body ng-app="CameraApp" ng-controller="cameraController">
<br/><br/>
<div align="center">
    <img id="myImage" ng-src="{{ imageSrc }}" ng-click="TakePicture();"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="TakePicture();" value="TAKE PICTURE" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" ng-disabled="{{ savePict }}" value="SAVE PICTURE"/>
</div>
```

**THE JS**

```
var app = angular.module('CameraApp', ['ngTouch']);

app.controller('cameraController', function ($scope) {

$scope.savePict = true;
$scope.imageSrc = '';


$scope.TakePicture = function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });
}

function onSuccess(imageUri) {
    $scope.imageSrc = imageUri;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "";
    $scope.savePict = true;
  } 
});
```

Comment: bind ng-click somewhere else outside image

Answer (score 0):

solved this way

```
function onSuccess(imageUri) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.imageSrc = imageUri;
    })
}
```

Comment: if you use `$window.navigator` instead of `navigator` in `TakePicture` you might actually get it to work without calling `$apply` because everything stay in AngularJS sync.